# How to run a single test with a different set of test data in CYPRESS

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have a need to run one test but at the same time transfer different test data to it. For example:

```
        it('example test',  () => {
        //first run
        getOnDefaultForm.typePhoneNumber('+7');
        getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();
        getOnDefaultForm.errorMessage();
        //second run
        getOnDefaultForm.typePhoneNumber('+7111');
        getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();
        getOnDefaultForm.errorMessage();
        //third run
        getOnDefaultForm.typePhoneNumber('+7111111');
        getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();
        getOnDefaultForm.errorMessage();
    });
```

Tell me how to do this more easily? Unfortunately could not be found in the documentation for cypress. Thank!

Answer (score 2):

You can put your `test data` in an array and generate the `test cases` in this way:

```
['+7', '+7111', '+7111111'].forEach((phoneNumber) => {
    it(`example test when entered phone number is ${phoneNumber}`,  () => {
        getOnDefaultForm.typePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();
        getOnDefaultForm.errorMessage();
    });
});
```

Comment: Happy to help :)...Please also mark the answer as 'accepted' to mark your question as 'answered'.